# How do I place text in a button in multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

I'm working on inserting a button that will span 6 columns with the labels being self-generating, but I want to split these labels into columns. In my head the code would look like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

Testbtn = Button(root, text="Column0".grid(column=0, row=1), text="Column1".grid(column=1,row=1), etc.)
Testbtn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=6)
```

I know that's not the correct approach, but I think it illustrates my intent. I'm sure there's someway that this is possible, but I've struggled to find any resources on this particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't split the text of a single button across multiple columns. You can add multiple labels inside the button, but then the button will not work like a proper button anymore, and the text won't align with columns outside of the button.

Comment: Do you think it would theoretically be possible for me to create a function that counts the characters of the text in the button and then automatically adds spaces? For example, it would register the word "text" as being 4 characters, would require a total of 10 characters, and would insert 6 additional " " after text to reach it's 10 character req? Not asking you to write the function for me, just wondering if you'd think it's possible. If so I could mimic columns inside a button using some function like that, but if not I'll just string the text together. Not a huge issue, just a preference